# No Network on GCE instance

Tags: centos7, google-compute-engine

I have a Centos7 instance on GCE that just stopped accept any connection. (no ping, ssh, http, nothing..)
from serial port I can see these errors:

```
ntpd_intres[336]: host name not found: metadata.google.internal

NetworkManager: /usr/sbin/NetworkManager: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgudev-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset

systemd: NetworkManager.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a

systemd: Failed to start Network Manager.

Bringing up interface eth0:  ERROR    : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Device  does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth: Device  does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
```

Any idea what the issue might be or I can I get in to try and fix this?
Any help or guidance will be appreciated

Comment: This looks like that the `libgudev-1.0.so.0` library file is incorrect version, which lacks the function required by `NetworkManager`. This causes the initialization to fail. Unfortunately I don't know how you can get a correct version of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can [interact](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) with the instance from the serial port output. If for some reason interacting with the serial port output doesn't resolve your issue, you will need to [attach the root disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) to another instance where you are able to ssh in order to fix the issue. However, make sure to take a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of the disk before going forward just for backup purposes.